# I'm trying to add a percentage value on a attribute that uses a number

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, react-arborist

I have a Tree component from the library React Arborist.

This component has a default height and I can modify it by using the prop height.
(for example: height={700})

The problem is: I want it to be **responsive** and this prop is using pixels, instead it should be %. However, this props only accepts numbers, not strings like '100%'.

Does anyone know how could I fix this?

I have tried by adding a className with a property height using the rule style !important and it worked but this is a terrible practice.

Also I tried to add an external component but the styles from the Tree are strongest I guess because it is inside.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify the `height`? Could you wrap it with a wrapper component and set its height to your desired height? If not, I would just use `!important`, as I don't see any other option.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as OGreeni... Can you just extend/wrap the Tree class/function and do your own percent to pixel calculation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would ask here https://github.com/brimdata/react-arborist/issues